# Significant pauses with EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I asked this on Amazon's forums and got no response so I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight.

We have been investigating the possibility of moving our web application to the cloud. However, I have occasionally experienced speed difficulties using EC-2. For instance, just now I was trying to remove a folder with 70k of stuff in it, about 10 files. It took approximately 2 minutes to do the deletion.

Once the deletion was over, I looked at top.

```
top - 21:54:45 up 5:53, 3 users, load average: 6.46, 4.22, 2.87
Tasks: 77 total, 1 running, 76 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 0.0%us, 0.0%sy, 0.0%ni,100.0%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 7652552k total, 5866044k used, 1786508k free, 131636k buffers
Swap: 0k total, 0k used, 0k free, 5394792k cached
```

6.46 load?! really? The 3 users are all me, two idle sftp connections and one ssh shell connection, from which I was running rm.

By the time the rm command was finished, all processes were running normally. After a minute, load was back down to 0.01.

I am using the Amazon EC2 ami from Feb 2011, large instance, with no servers running. It's just a base install.

Is it possible that other instances on the machine are generating this high load?  Or could there be something with the Amazon AMI that is causing it?

Comment: What's the AMI-number? Which type op EC2 Micro/Large/... ? Type of storage?

Comment: What percentage of the CPU usage was iowait during the deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EBS for storage? Such weird slow disk access might be normal-but-unspoken:

[Reddit had some problems with it](http://www.reddit.com/r/blog/comments/g66f0/why_reddit_was_down_for_6_of_the_last_24_hours/c1l6ykx)